# Resolve dependencies when building project with meson

Tags: meson-build, wayland

I'm building with meson but every time i run the command

```
meson setup _build .
```

I got asked regarding some dependency library I'm supposed to have on my system (is a fresh installed one).
I manually install the dependency and start over running the build command again but I smash my face on another dependency.
Am I supposed to do that manually one by one or is there any trick I'm not aware of?
As you can notice I'm a newbie

I'm trying to build from source a custom libinput on wayland apps to enable three fingers drag on my mac
This one:
https://github.com/aakside/libinput/tree/1.16-branch-complyue

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to resolve dependencies automatically using Meson.  Most projects will either document the dependencies or support another tool such as Conan.

In this case, the dependencies are documented here: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html#build-dependencies